# re.findall : Inserting a variable value in regex failing when {} already used for range of occurences to match

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am searching a string `text0` for the following value:

```
text0='abcABC="34">123.12</td><'
```

I use `re.findall`, and I am substituting a variable at the position of 34.When it works using the `re.findall`, `listaa` gets the value of `123.12`.

I can use `{}` to put the variable `count1` and I get the value I want:  `123.12`

```
count1=34

listaa =re.findall('abcABC="{}">+([0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9])+</td><'.format(count1),text0)
```

Also, the following works fine: hard coding the value `34`, and getting flexibility for the answer i want by using this:  `[0-9]{1,3}` (selecting between 1 and 3 numbers of 0-9 to the left of the decimal point).

```
listaa =re.findall('abcABC="34">+([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9][0-9])+</td><',text0)
```

But I can't get this to work when I use both types of uses for `{}` at the same time.

```
listaa =re.findall('abcABC="{}">+([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9][0-9])+</td><'.format(count1),text0)
```

I get the following error:

```
KeyError 1,3
```

How can I get the last statement to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `{{` and `}}` to denote literal `{` and `}` when using the `str.format` method:

```
listaa =re.findall('abcABC="{}">+([0-9]{{1,3}}.[0-9][0-9])+</td><'.format(count1),text0)
```

Comment: You are right.  I used {{}} for the literal case and it works fine.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you find it to be correct? (Click on the grey check mark next to the question.)

Comment: I still find it confusing that the literal case does not require {{}} if I am not inserting a variable using .format.  Is there a theoretical reason for that? But of course it works, and I can remember that.

Comment: This is because `str.format` parses the string first, looking for `{}`s to replace with its arguments, and then the string formatted by `str.format` then gets passed to `re.findall`, which then treats anything between an unescaped pair of `{` and `}` as a quantifier. So if the `{1,3}` are to be preserved for `re.findall` to parse, you need to prevent `str.format` from interpreting `{` and `}` by escaping them, and the way `str.format` escapes `{` and `}` is by doubling them. That's all.

Comment: Thank you.  Its useful to know that str.format parses the string first.